# Date and time (two fields) convert into UTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have two fields:

- Date
- Time

and I have managed to show/display dates in user's time zone, but store data in UTC (in state) because I want to send API request and store all times in UTC.

However, I have a problem when I select:

- 7th September 2020
- 00:30

This means that I need to set 6th September 22:30 (if we assume that my time zone is Europe/Berlin.

This is how I display date:

```
    const date = moment.utc(selected).tz(localStorage.getItem('format_timezone')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const newSelected = selected ? new Date(date) : '';
```

and this is how I display time:

```
 const date = moment.utc().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    const time = moment.utc(`${date} ${selected}`).tz(localStorage.getItem('format_timezone')).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
    const newSelected = selected ? new Date(time) : '';
```

and this is how I handle input change:

```
handleDateInput(e) {
        const { setCampaignInputs } = this.props;
        setCampaignInputs('date_input', moment(e).format(convertToMoment('Y-m-d')));
    }

    handleTimeInput(e) {
        const { setCampaignInputs } = this.props;
        setCampaignInputs('time_input', moment.utc(e).format(convertToMoment('H:i:s')));
    }
```

Any tips how to handle this if I store data in two field? It would be easy if I store data in one input field...

Thanks!

Comment: "Any tips how to handle this if I store data in two field?" Do you want tips or do you want a solution to a specific problem?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to convert a user's time into UTC time, based on the title.  But the body of the question does the opposite of clarify.

Comment: @GirkovArpa I want to select let's say in one field September 8th 01:00 (my time zone is Europe/Berlin e.g.) but in React state it should be September 7th 23:00. The problem is that I select date (8th september) when I have no information about time, and then time. Obivously, I should update again, but always I somehow fail to do that. Tip is okay  and I can later write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with date/time in javascript is by using epochMilli. From epochMilli to date using new Date(epochMilli) whatever timezone the browsers are. And From Date to epochMilli is by using getTime() method.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

On user-input you'll have the `inputDate` and `inputTime` strings.  That same string can be utilized to generate the state value and also the display value (which will be rendered from state)

```js
const inputDate = '2020-01-01'
const inputTime = '00:30'
const stateValue = moment(`${inputDate} ${inputTime}`)
  .utc()
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
const displayDateTime = moment(`${stateValue}Z`)
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
const displayDate = moment(`${stateValue}Z`).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
const displayTime = moment(`${stateValue}Z`).format('HH:mm');
console.log('state-value : ', stateValue) // state value
console.log('display-date-time : ', displayDateTime) // date-time display value
console.log('display-date : ', displayDate) // date display value
console.log('display-time : ', displayTime) // time display value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Good Luck...